# What does `static:rest` in the Postfix configuration mean?

Tags: postfix, configuration

In the Postfix configuration line (main.cf)

```
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = !ntlm, static:rest
```

what is the meaning of “static:rest”?  While `static:` is explained in Postfix’ documentation as yielding the string `rest` as is, I can only assume that `rest` means “all not explicitly excluded mechanisms”. However, then there also is ”static:all” – is this an alias for ”static:rest”?

And: What would be the meaning of a naked `!ntlm` without `static:rest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list has to yield a result for *all* acceptable mechanisms.

If you want to exclude entries without explicitly enumerating what remains, you need something in that list to match all remaining entries. This is not possible by just removing mechanisms using the exclamation mark, the list would remain empty and *none* of the mechanisms could be used. That is where the `static:` entry comes in. It always matches.

Its return, a.k.a. *the right-hand side* is entirely ignored. Yes, `static:all` would have the same *effect*, the verbosity only serves to clarify the *intent*. Its not all mechanisms, it is all mechanisms not already matched by a previous entry in the filter specification.

---

If you are looking for better examples of how this works, lookup how the exclamation mark in `mynetworks` works. But not `smtp_tls_protocols`, that one is different, that one is customized for its essentially numeric lookups.

I really hope this is confusing interaction between lookups and exclusions is eventually fixed by introducing a true boolean-type behaviour for relevant lookup maps, but I do not know of a way to do so in a safe, backwards-compatible manner.